# Open Facebook APP URL in the Facebook Android app instead of browser

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-apps

i noticed that when I click on a Facebook App Url inside Facebook Mobile App on Android, the app is opened/redirect in the browser and not inside the Facebook app. Instead if I open the app in an IOS device, the app is opened inside Facebook app. Why? Can I have the same behaviour in Android device?

You can test the problem here:

1. Take an Android device
2. Open the facebook app and go to https://apps.facebook.com/1431973097077103 (you have to do a post with this link to click on it)
3. Android device redirect to browser, IOS device remain inside Facebook

Thanks!

Comment: :i think the older facebook sdk offers that kind of approach, i dunno correctly, try to use the latest facebook sdk for android,in that facebook inbuilt app is opened

Comment: it is a web app not android.. we use javascript sdk

Comment: Canvas is not supported on Mobile

Comment: Its not true. With my iPhone i open my app inside facebook without problem. The problem are android devices that redirect in the browser..